# Semantics3 API with AngularJS Authentication

Tags: api, angularjs, oauth

I am in the process of learning AngularJS. I am building a mobile first application using bootstrap 3.1.0.

Basically I want to consume the Semantics3 API and display the products in a list. How can I do this when Semantics3's API needs authentication via OAuth. I already have my API `key` and `secret`, but I do not know how to successfully make the call to the API from my Angular controller.

At the moment my code looks like so:

```
savvyShop.controller('ProductsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.apiResult = $http.get('https://api.semantics3.com/v1/products?q={"cat_id":13658,"brand":"Toshiba","model":"Satellite"}')
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there would be no way you can do this from the client-side (via AJAX). This is because you're trying to make a cross-domain request, which all Javascript engines do not allow. In general, if the API provides a JSONP endpoint, you could use that to make cross-domain requests. However, Semantics3 does not have one.

You could write a server-side script that effectively acts as a proxy between the client and our Semantics3 servers. It would basically pass on whatever queries you send to our URL, receive the results, and send it to the client. That way, you can use $http.get in AngularJS to run those queries.

Comment: +1 for server-side script. That way even your credentials are hidden from the client!